# Como eliminar registros masivos duplicados con SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delete

Necesito eliminar registros de una DB de SQL Server que se fueron almacenando con los años, el problema es que son mas de 31millones de registros.

Utilizo un ejemplo que encontre en la pagina de Microsoft, cuando lo intento ejecutar el servidor se queda sin espacio, hay manera de hacer esto con algun tipo de chunk? En una db de prueba demora hasta 9 horas con la mitad de registros

```
SELECT
        rev,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                sucursal_id,
                calle,
                altura,
                tel,
                puerta,
                orden
            ORDER BY
                sucursal_id,
                calle,
                altura,
                tel,
                puerta,
                orden
        ) row_num
    FROM
        dir_audit
)


DELETE FROM dir_audit WHERE rev in (SELECT rev FROM lista WHERE row_num > 1)
```

Comment: Probaste crear una nueva tabla con la restriccion de que todas las columnas sean claves, y copiar todos los registros? obviamente, los duplicados van a dar error y no van a ser copiados....

Comment: Cual es el criterio de duplicidad que estas usando para saber cuales registros eliminar?

Comment: Los campos sucursal_id,calle,altura,tel,puerta,orden son los que no tienen que estar duplicados

Comment: Son más de 31 millones de filas a eliminar, pero cuantas van a permanecer? Son más o menos?

Comment: Agrega un TOP n al select, donde n sea, 100.000  (o un numero manejable) y ejecutas la consulta las veces que sea necesario para eliminar todo

Comment: Yo he logrado realizar operaciones con duplicados usando la clausula HAVING combinada con COUNT. Lo que haces básicamente es recorrer toda tu tabla, y donde el conteo sea mayor a 1 es porque es un renglón duplicado. Te dejo la documentación oficial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @ErnestoRincon como quedaria? No se si es mucho pedir la query, no tengo mucha noción sobre sql

Comment: ¿rev es la llave primaria o, al menos, es único?

Comment: @jachguate asi es, el campo rev es unico

Comment: Podrías agregar a tu pregunta la estructura de tu tabla? Tengo idea de como poder ayudarte pero quiero aclarar unas dudas antes.

Comment: @ErnestoRincon solo el campo id y rev son primary key, los demas no

Answer (score 0):

No conozco la estructura de tu tabla pero creo que esto puede ayudarte o acercarte bastante a una solución. Yo anidaría dentro del DELETE la consulta donde sabré los ID que debo eliminar siempre y cuando se cumpla la condición de que el renglón este duplicado:

```sql
DELETE FROM dir_audit WHERE sucursal_id IN(
    SELECT  sucursal_id,
            COUNT(sucursal_id) AS conteo_sucursal,
            COUNT(calle) AS conteo_calle,
            COUNT(altura) As conteo_altura,
            COUNT(tel) AS conteo_tel,
            COUNT(puerta) AS conteo_puerta,
            COUNT(orden)  AS conteo_orden
    FROM dir_audit 
    GROUP BY
            sucursal,
            calle,
            altura,
            tel,
            puerta,
            orden
    HAVING COUNT(conteo_sucursal) > 1 AND 
           COUNT(conteo_calle) > 1 AND
           COUNT(conteo_altura) > 1 AND
           COUNT(conteo_tel) > 1 AND
           COUNT(conteo_puerta) > 1 AND
           COUNT(conteo_orden) > 1);
```

Usando como criterio el ID de la sucursal, contabilizamos la cantidad de elementos a comparar, luego las agrupamos y validamos que se repitan mas de una vez todos los valores especificados indicando la duplicidad. Se procede a realizar la eliminación de estos con el DELETE en base a lo retornado por el sub-query.

La consulta puede que sea un poco confusa pero según tu solicitud debes evaluar todos los criterios cuando lo común es que sea uno solo.

Comment: Hola, sucede lo mismo, me quedo sin espacio